# when to release the record in the input buffer with the @ in sas?

Tags: sas

The following is the simple SAS program:

```
data mydata;
  do group = 'placebo', 'active';
     do subj = 1 to 5;
        input score @;
        output;
     end;
  end;

datalines;
250 222 230 210 199
166 183 123 129 234
;
```

I am learning SAS by myself. So I was thinking to make sure what happens here. For my understanding, the first line of the 5 entries belongs to the group placebo and the second line belongs to the group active. At first, the input buffer contains the first line of the 5 numbers, and the do subj=1 to 5 prints them out one by one, until the end of the current data step iteration. Then, the data step continues with the second iteration. Is this understanding correct? Many thanks for your time and attention.

PS. I just want to make sure when to release the current input buffer. After checking online, I found that the purpose of the @ is as the following:

holds an input record for the execution of the next INPUT statement within the same iteration of the DATA step. This line-hold specifier is called trailing @.

So, it means the input buffer is released if one of the following two conditions is met:

(1): A new input statement is met without any @ or @@.
(2): The end of the current data step iteration.

Any comments are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work fine, but you should see a note that SAS went to a new line in your LOG.

When GROUP='placebo' the inner loop (DO SUBJ ...) will read 5 numbers and leave the pointer at the end of the first line.  Then the outer loop will execute again with GROUP='active'. When it tries to read the SCORE for SUBJ=1 there is nothing left on the first line.  So SAS will skip to the next line and read the first SCORE from there.  Then the other four values are read from that line.

Finally at the end of the data step it will "release" the line so the pointer will be at the beginning of line three (if there was a line three).

Then the whole data step will loop one more time and set GROUP='placebo' and SUBJ=1, but when it tries to read the SCORE it reads past the end of the file and stops the data step.

Note that your program would work fine as long as you have 10 values spaced over as many lines as you want.

Comment: So I would get an error message if the @ is deleted?

Comment: Nope. Without the trailing @ you would just get two observations in your data set for GROUP='placebo', SUBJ=1 and 2 and SCORE = 250 and 166. The data step would stop when you tried to execute the INPUT statement for the third time since there are only two lines in your data.

Comment: Moreover, if the do subj = 1 to 5 is changed to do subj = 1 to 2, then, the placebo group would have 250 222 199 166 129 234 and the active group would have 230 210 183 123?

Comment: The thing to do it play with it. Put some PUT statements in there so you can see what values the variables have at different points.

Answer (score 1):

I like Tom's answer, but want to expand a bit on the meaning of data step iteration.  You wrote:

> At first, the input buffer contains the first line of the 5 numbers, and the do subj=1 to 5 prints them out one by one, until the end of the current data step iteration. Then, the data step continues with the second iteration. Is this understanding correct?

The DATA step is an implied iterative loop, from the top (DATA statement) to the bottom (RUN statement typically, in this case I think DATALINES statement).  If you want to see what happens on each iteration of the loop, you can write values to the log with the PUT statement, you can also write *N* to the log, which is a counter for DATA step iteration number.  So you might change your code to:

```
do group = 'placebo', 'active';
   do subj = 1 to 5;
      input score @;
      put _n_= score= ;
      output;
   end;
end;
```

If you do that you should see that all of the data (all 10 values from both rows) are processed on the first iteration of the DATA step.  You should only see `_n_=1` in the log.  As @Tom explained, this is because in the explicit looping you wrote, SAS moves forward to the second line of data when it can't find a sixth value to read on the first line.  I think most people would consider the NOTE SAS throws about moving to the next line as a warning or even error.

If you want to have two iterations of the DATA step loop, you could change to something like:

```
if _n_=1 then group = 'placebo';
else if _n_=2 then group= 'active';

do subj = 1 to 5;
  input score @;
  put _n_= score= ;
  output;
end;
```

(Not suggesting that two iterations is better, or that the above code is better, point is just to show what data step iteration means).

Comment: Excellent point. So, SAS data step starts the second iteration only for certain input data? Like only for SAS data set as input or things like that? Or when will SAS data step starts the second iteration?

Comment: The data step always iterates, until it reaches a condition that makes it stop. In this case it reads all that data on the first iteration. Then it iterates a second time, and when the input statement hits the end of the file, the step stops.  If you add put _ n _= at the top of the data step, you should see it write _ n _ = 2 on the second iteration. A key to learning the DATA step is learning about the iteration, when it stops, etc. These are good questions to be thinking through.